# Combining multiple objects in an array for json using Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I'm using the grape gem in my rails application. When returning a single record I can use the grape active model serializer. When returning multiple objects I run into an undefined error. How should I structure my multiple campaign records?

**app/controllers/api/v1/campaigns.rb**

**Returning Multiple records**

```
  resource :campaigns do

    desc "Return all campaigns"
    get "", root: :campaigns do
        @campaign_array = []
        @campaigns = Campaign.all
        @campaigns.each do |campaign|
            @campaign_array << {
              backers: campaign.orders.count,
              funded: campaign.orders.completed.sum(:quantity),
              campaign: campaign
            }
        end
        @campaign_array
    end
  end
```

**Output - Error**

```
undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization'
```

**Returning a single record**

```
    desc "Return a campaign"
    get ":id", root: :campaign do

        @campaign = Campaign.where(id: permitted_params[:id]).first!
        {
          backers: @campaign.orders.count,
          funded: @campaign.orders.completed.sum(:quantity),
          campaign: @campaign
        }
    end
```

**Output**

```
{
    "backers": 1,
    "funded": 2,
    "campaign": {
        "id": 5,
        "min_funding_goal_units": 20,
        "product_name": "Another product",
        "product_description": "A product description",
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you return an array which is not serialized.

- Does your `index` works if you just return `@campaigns` ? (just to be sure that the problem come from the serialization)
- Maybe can you try to «help»  Grape by indicating `format :json` below `get "", root: :campaigns do`

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use each_serializer instead of serializer when it's an
>   array of items

There is an issue in github about this problem. Related [issue](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-active_model_serializers/issues/23).